# VBA Macro or Conditional Formatting to identify the Specified case numbers

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, excel-2010

Sample Data: [image]

Expected result:[image]

Datatable:

| Suborder_ID | SUBJ_FIRST_NAME | SUBJ_LAST_NAME | SUPPLR_ID | case_number | Case Types |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 296305917 | SUSAN | LYNCH | 772NC | 01CR 030779 | CR |
| 296305917 | SUSAN | LYNCH | 772NC | 03CR 056572 | CR |
| 296305917 | SUSAN | LYNCH | 772NC | 01D 030779 | D Cases |
| 296305917 | SUSAN | LYNCH | 772NC | 03CR 056572 | D Cases |
| 296305122 | JESSICA | PURDY | 772NC | 22CR 719383 | D Cases |
| 296305122 | JESSICA | PURDY | 772NC | 22CR 734624 | D Cases |
| 296305122 | JESSICA | PURDY | 772NC | 12CR 219981 | D Cases |
| 296306462 | JEFFREY | HOWARD | 772NC | 10CR 706096 | CR |
| 296306462 | JEFFREY | HOWARD | 772NC | 10CRS 706096 | CRS |
| 296306462 | JEFFREY | HOWARD | 772NC | 09CR 734576 | D Cases |
| 296314697 | ANTONIO | COWARD | 772NC | 14CR 744035 | D Cases |
| 296314697 | ANTONIO | COWARD | 772NC | 16CR 730615 | D Cases |
| 296314697 | ANTONIO | COWARD | 772NC | 17D 768617 | D Cases |
| 296314697 | ANTONIO | COWARD | 772NC | 17S 768617 | S Cases |
| 298183468 | KEVIN | REMMER | 971NC | 19CRS 725453 | CRS |
| 298183468 | KEVIN | REMMER | 971NC | 19S 725453 | S Cases |
| 291903468 | EBONY | EDDIE | 34NC | 11CRS 030779 | CRS |
| 291903468 | EBONY | EDDIE | 78NC | 22CR 734629 | CR |
| 291903468 | EBONY | EDDIE | 09NC | 22CR 764629 | CR |
| 291903468 | EBONY | EDDIE | 09NC | 11D 706096 | CR |

I tried to identify the same Case numbers contain different alphabets like D,CR, CRS, and S, so I applied `=RIGHT(E2, 6)` to take the last six digits, and if a number greater than 1 is mentioned as `exist`, else it `does not exist`, but for some cases the number repeated in other suborder ids is also expected result  is getting collapsed.

can anyone help?

Comment: It seems you already got your desired result. What is you question. Post data as text table with pictures so that we can copy.

Comment: Can you explain the logic why row 18 should show as " Does not exist"? Case_number is 030779 which occurs e.g. in row 1 and row 3 as well. Second question: are you really on excel-2010 - screenshots don't look like that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) is your friend. With that formula, it is possible to combine multiple criterias.
Your first criteria is that the suborder ID is matching, the second is that the Case Number is matching.

Assuming that you have the helper column in M (with the formula `=RIGHT(E2, 6)`), the formula for col O would be

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,M:M,M2)>1,"Exists","Does Not Exist")
```

If you want to use this in conditional formatting without helper column O, simply use `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,M:M,M2)>1` as formula

Comment: thanks for your help and i found alternate option also  =CONCATENATE(RIGHT(E2,6),"_",A2) to make it as unique